# In meteorjs' click event, how do I get the id?

Tags: meteor

In meteorjs's event, how do I get the id of clicked item, without adding a JQuery binding stuff?

(Ya I investigated other posts, but does not help) IMPOV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
{
  'click p': function (event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
  }
}
```

Read more [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps).

Comment: Thanks! In the mean time, I figured it out by trial and error. The bugging structure of event object (for a newbee) is that some node of the hierarchy hold a value as well, not just a path, and the hierarchy format may lead to confusion, but once we get used to it, it works. Example: pageX seems embedded in upper levels, but it is not, so can be accessed directly.